# Create a Context/Condition and get a view display used on the page

Tags: views, 9, plugins

I want to create a context/condition plugin that checks the total results returned from a view display on the page (its a block), and if its less/greater than a certain figure, hide certain peripheral display elements.

I cannot seem to find a ContextDefinition for the view being executed, does this exist? Do I need to grab the context from the Block itself? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up writing a specific module for this.

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_minimum